# Installscript - Deleting sites from IIS uninstallation

Tags: installshield

I am using Installshield 2012 Spring Edition. I have created a setup project. While uninstallation, I need to delete the files from IIS and stop the services automatically. I have tried using some installscript codes. But, I am getting this error:

"error 2762: cannot write script record transaction not started"

Can anyone tell me, is there any other method to do this operation.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Naren.

Answer (score 0):

When are you sequencing your custom action? Also what type is your custom action?

If you are trying to execute a deferred custom action then it needs to be sequenced between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize.

Could you provide a snippet of your install script?